# Azure Table Storage entity size limitations

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

How do you calculate the exact size of a table entity? 
Referring to this [very old blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/avkashchauhan/how-the-size-of-an-entity-is-caclulated-in-windows-azure-table-storage) the formula is:

```
4 bytes + Len (PartitionKey + RowKey) * 2 bytes + For-Each Property(8 bytes + Len(Property Name) * 2 bytes + Sizeof(.Net Property Type))
```

where

```
String – # of Characters * 2 bytes + 4 bytes for length of string
DateTime – 8 bytes
GUID – 16 bytes
Double – 8 bytes
Int – 4 bytes
INT64 – 8 bytes
Bool – 1 byte
Binary – sizeof(value) in bytes + 4 bytes for length of binary array
```

Is this still valid? There are other sources on the web where the property name is not included into the calculation.

Thank you for a short confirmation.

Comment: added the azure tag to reach more people ;-)

Comment: I believe the formula for calculation is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is still valid.

You can review the doc(published in ‎**12-12-2019 09:33 PM**) [Calculate the size/capacity of storage account and it services (Blob/Table)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-developer-blog/calculate-the-size-capacity-of-storage-account-and-it-services/ba-p/1064046) in **Microsoft Tech Community** -> in this section **8. Calculate the size of each entity in azure storage table.**. I also attach the screenshot as below:

[image]